# error destroy return not found 404 in laravel 7.30.4 Please help me too

Tags: laravel

In my controller I have this

```
public function delete($id){
      
        Partneruser::destroy($id);
        Session()->flash("success","ลบข้อมูลเรียบร้อยแล้ว!");
        return redirect('Admin/createPartnerAg');
    }
```

In my view, I have this

```
<td scope="col" class="text-danger bg-dark"><a href="/admin/deletePartnerAg/{{$partneruser->id}}"  onclick="return confirm('คุณต้องการลบข้อมูลหรือไม่?')" ><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></td>
```

In my Route web.php, I have this

```
Route::get('Admin/deletePartnerAg/{id}', 'admin\PartnerUserController@delete')->middleware('auth:admin');`enter code here`
```

php artisan route:list

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEjwX.jpg)

It keeps redirecting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8YXt.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in `web.php`, `get` and `post` request cant be used for deletes with an `<a>` tag.

instead of  use a form :

```
<form method="post" ... >
    @csrf
    @method{"DELETE"}
    <button type="submit" >delete </button>
</form>
```

then change the route

```
Route::delete('Admin/deletePartnerAg/{id}', ...
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.... you mixed up captial letter

```html
<td scope="col" class="text-danger bg-dark"><a href="/Admin/deletePartnerAg/{{$partneruser->id}}"  onclick="return confirm('คุณต้องการลบข้อมูลหรือไม่?')" ><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></td>
```

Comment: I'm try already result 404 Not Found. The same